# Create an Azure AD with different On premise AD name

Tags: entra-id

I'm trying to connect my On premise AD name : DOMAININT.ORG to my azure ad with a domaine name : DOMAINE.org.
On my office 365 all my user have their email adresses.

All configuration are good, i installed the plugin azure ad connect and configure it.

But i have a question. How can i link my office 365 user (azure ad) with my on premise ad. Because they have two differente domaine name.

Sorry for my english, i hope i explained corectly my question.

Have a good day.

Comment: Did you already have Office 365 accounts before you synced your on premises user accounts to Office 365? If so, do you now have two user accounts in Office 365 for each person?

Comment: Hello, yes i already have a office 365 before i started the syn and all my user are already created in the two side (separately). And i have an error when i try to synchronize :ExtraErrorDetails:
[{"Key":"ObjectId","Value":["988e5b29-f0c9-4bf6-9416-7a7a3903078d"]},{"Key":"ObjectIdInConflict","Value":["190811b2-0c8b-497b-90c0-bcd7bb94a6e5"]},{"Key":"AttributeConflictName","Value":["ProxyAddresses"]},{"Key":"AttributeConflictValues","Value":["SMTP:XXXXX@DOMAINE.org"]}]

Comment: The error deseapear , a deleted the @mail. But two accounts are create. But how can i link the two different account in one ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to match the on premises users to the existing Office 365 users.

To do that you'll need to unsync the on premises users and permanently delete them in Office 365, then resync them, after making a few changes:

1. Reconfigure Azure AD Connect to sync an empty OU.
2. This will delete the synced users in Office 365. Make sure that only the on premises synced user accounts are deleted in Office 365. You then need to remove these users from Deleted users in Office 365.
3. Create a UPN suffix in your on premises AD that matches your verified domain in Office 365. This UPN suffix should be the same as the User Principal Name (login name) of your Office 365 user accounts. Example: UPN Suffix = mycompany.com, UPN = JohnDoe@mycompany.com
4. Set this UPN suffix on all of your on premises user accounts.
5. Reconfigure Azure AD Connect to sync your entire domain.
6. The on premises users should now sync and match to the existing Office 365 users.